# How to Include sub module dependency when publish library with maven-publish

Tags: maven-publish

I have 2 modules, first one is `module-to-publish`, second one is `module-base`. Now I want to publish `module-to-publish` to mavenCentral with `module-base` inside. What should I do to include `module-base`.